# Why my Macbook Pro 13 2017 battery lasts just 4h?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I was expecting this MacBook Pro 13 (without Touch Bar) up to 10h of battery and I'm getting just 4h.

Moreover, the screen is off since I'm using an external monitor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried how long time it will hold battery? - I.e. not just look at those stats from a third-party battery program. It might be that they calculate the running time in a manner not consistent with actual real life experience.

Comment: @jksoegaard, I've added a screenshot of Apple Energy stats. Seems it's on the line of those third-party apps.

Comment: That MacBook Pro has integrated graphics (on the CPU) and driving an external screen requires more CPU than driving the LCD.  Have you actually gotten only 4 hours or are you basing it on the calculations of a 3rd party app?  Finally, what does your activity monitor look like?  What are you doing?

Comment: Time remaining isn’t total time.  How long was it on battery *prior* to getting that screen shot?

Comment: I’ll do a full battery session with the external 4K display. Also consider that the laptop display is on (but dimmed) since I’m using integrated keyboard